# Ant filterset task not recursing

Tags: ant

Using Apache Ant 1.7.1

It looks like the Ant Filter task can't resolve the same property several times in one line when recurse is set to true. I can't find any mention of this in the Ant docs. Is this supposed to happen?

Using this ant build file:

```
<project basedir="." default="assemble" >
  <macrodef name="copy-and-filter">
    <sequential>
      <copy tofile="to.txt" file="from.txt" overwrite="true">
        <filterset recurse="true">
          <filtersfile file="filters.properties"/>
        </filterset>
      </copy>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

  <target name="assemble">
    <copy-and-filter />
  </target>
</project>
```

with these files:

from.txt:

```
I want my broker to be: @broker.url@
and my client to be: @client.url@
```

filters.properties:

```
myval=fish
broker.url=-@myval@-
client.url=@myval@-@myval@
```

I get the output to be:

```
i want my broker to be: -fish-
and my client to be: myval
```

and not what I expected which would be this:

```
i want my broker to be: -fish-
and my client to be: fish-fish
```

If I set recurse to false then I get the 'correct' behaviour.

```
i want my broker to be: -@myval@-
and my client to be: @myval@-@myval@
```

Why is this?

Comment: The code works for later versions of Ant in the way you want.  There was an Ant bug for this: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44226 It seems fixed in 1.8.0 and 1.81.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurse flag is intended to look for more tokens after an initial replace occurs, but it won't work if the same token is used again. The problem is that setting recurse=true causes an infinite loop. See the output from Ant:

```
Infinite loop in tokens. Currently known token tokens: [client.url, myval]
Problem token: @myval@ called from @myval@
```

I don't think its possible to do what you want to be able to do using the filterset task. What are you using the to.txt file for? Is it to provide a system configuration file?

Comment: Yes this error was being hidden by my IDE. 
I'll have to rethink what I'm doing here.